# The framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '3.1.0' (x64) was not found

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-framework-version

I face this issue in visual studio 2022 and i use dotnet core 3.1
netcoreapp3.1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xglPi.png)

Comment: Does your visual studio  2022 have a dotnet core 3.1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In Visual Studio Installer, choose modify

[image]

2.In Individual components, choose .NET Core 3.1 Runtime, and modify

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to install .NET core 3.1 framework SDK on your system. You can download from
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/3.1